# Former manager giving bad reference

Tags: interviewing, manager

About 3 years ago I worked for a large bank. It was a temp job for 6 months. I loved working there and want to go back. I have good friends there. Each time that an opportunity presented itself my former boss doesn't recommend me. I have great recommendations from everywhere else. I think she felt that me and this other guy from the team were too close and she probably felt like I spent more time with him. If that is the case she isn't completely wrong. But this doesn't characterise me and it won't be repeated... I work hard. I want to speak to her... but don't know what to say and how? Face to face or phone? The guy that I was friends with still works there. She isn't his boss now but I guess it concerns her. Please give me advice.
Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask here. Why are you still using your old boss as a reference if you know she won't recommend you? Are you applying to the company where she still works? Do the automatically ask her about you when you apply, even though you don't include her as a reference?

Comment: When you say "too close" do you mean you had an unprofessional (i.e. romantic or sexual) relationship? Or that you spent your time talking with this guy when you should have been working? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to have to tell you this, but you blew it. You behaved unprofessionally in a role; people aren't going to just forget that, no matter what glowing references you can provide from elsewhere. I'll always believe what I see and hear with my own eyes and ears over what other people say.

Your best bet here is to move on, and learn from the experience. Next time you find a great job where you really like working, remember to *do your job*; then you'll be welcome back in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure where you got "behaved unprofessionally" and "[didn't] do your job" from the OP's question. OP says they were closer with someone else on the team than they were with the boss, which doesn't necessarily translate to behaving unprofessionally and not doing the job.

Comment: @shoover, generally when managers go to the trouble of making sure someone is not rehired, there was some unprofessional behavior going on.

Comment: @HLGEM *"generally when managers go to the trouble of making sure someone is not rehired, there was some unprofessional behavior going on"* that is not necessarily true, an assumption, rather, based on the idea that managers are always right and employees are always wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I have worked with some people through the years who have had inappropriate relationships at work that affected the people around them. It could be inappropriate displays of affection (no kissing, hugging or touching of any kind at work) or it could descend into worse with incompetent people being promoted due to the relationship or it could be that one person knew things from the person they were in a relationship with that they should not have known. I would never recommend any of those people for re-hire or for hire at a new place because they were unable to behave professionally not because they had a relationship.

I have also worked with others who managed to behave professionally when they got into a relationship with a co-worker. Some of them are even married to that same co-worker now. I have no problem with them nor did any of the other people we worked with.

Your problem isn't that you had "Friendship" with this man, it is that you behaved badly at work while it was going on. That makes you unreliable in your former boss's eyes. Likely there were some messes caused by this that she had to clean up.

Alternatively, the boss was jealous and feels threatened by your relationship to this person. Even there, there is no going back. You aren't going to change this person's mind.

You don't get a do-over for this type of mistake. You are not ever going to be hired back by that organization until the manager is long gone and maybe not then depending on how your personnel file is marked.

You need to move on to other opportunities and you need to think very clearly about why your relationship caused a problem and how you are going to handle it the next time you are attracted to someone at work.

Comment: Ok let me clear things up..no inappropriate behaviour.no affair..he is married!No mess that she had to clean up. The guy is married but he always looked out for me and helped me out and i guess she didnt like it.this other girl thinks she has a crush on him.i thought so too. The job i was bought to do i did but it was never tested and i think changes were done after i left. The code i guess wasnt reat. We spent a lot of time together but i didnt behave badly.I was approached twice by other managers who knew i wanted to come back..she blocked it. Yes,she works for that bank.

Comment: @shoover..she works there.

Comment: @Collie: I'm not normally one to comment on spelling; however, I am wondering if perhaps the work you performed was of a similar quality to your written English skills.  If that's the case, then perhaps this "inappropriate" relationship wasn't the issue.  Either way, I'd say it's time to just move on.

Comment: @NotMe Notice that not all the jobs in the universe are to be performed in English: as such, comparing lack of English skills to lack of quality on the workplace is inappropriate, just to say the least.